# How to start my VM in VMware Fusion with little disk space available

Tags: macos, disk-space, vmware-fusion

Due to some newly installed software packages my MacBook (Mac OS X 10.6.7) runs with little disk space available (~ 2.3 gb), which actually is enough for working right now. Currently I am on the go so I can't transfer any data to other machines.

After said several installations my Windows 7 x64 VM does not start anymore. It refuses with a warning informing me that there's little disk space on host available and I should release about 230 mb to resume, otherwise the VM may experience an unexpected error. At this point I am asked to decide whether to continue or to stop the VM again. If I decide to continue the startup, the warning pops up again, which is the same case when I decide to continue again and so on...

Info: After launching the VM's start, the amount of disk space shrinks to ~ 1 gb.

Can anyone help? Thx in advance...

Cheers!

Comment: Did you perform a Cleanup? On three Windows VMs, I found 100 GB of reclaimable space. I'm now trying to permanently shrink it to avoid the problems. Also see [“Invalid disk size” when shrinking a disk](http://superuser.com/q/1095032) and [Dismiss low disk space prompt (Suspend, Power Off, Continue)](http://superuser.com/q/860750).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free some disk space (a completely full Mac OS X system disk is a major pain, you'll actually lose data) or move the VM to an external hard drive with enough free space. You wrote yourself, the VM gobbles up free space when running.