# "Invalid disk size" when shrinking a disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, vmware-fusion

My MacBook is running out of disk space. I found three Windows VM's that had almost 100 GB reclaimable space, so I reclaimed it. I'm now trying to permanently shrink it to [avoid the endless stream of storage issues and message boxes](https://superuser.com/q/860750/173513).

In the Windows VM guest, I used *Disk Management* to shrink the disk. There's 20 GB of unallocated space now:

[image]

With the VM powered off, I go to VMware Fusion Toolbox and attempt to shrink the drive by changing the disk size from 100 GB to 80 GB. However, it presents an ***Invalid disk size*** error:

[image]

And:

[image]

I found VMware's [KB 1001934: Defragmenting, shrinking, and cleaning up VMware Fusion virtual machine disks](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001934), but things are not working as expected. The KB also fails to discuss the error.

How do I permanently reclaim or shrink the disk in VMware Fusion 5?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reduce the drive size too much.  Looking at the drive sizes reported in Disk Management in Windows: `350MB` + `79.66GB` = `80.01GB`.  `80.01 > 80.00` -- try using a slightly larger size in VMware.

Comment: @Techie - My bad; the complete error message has been added. It appears VMware only wants to grow it, not shrink it.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try it with the VM powered off?

Comment: @Techie - Yes, it is powered off. Otherwise, all the settings in the second image are greyed out. (It was also added to the question).

Comment: That's what I figured, but always best to confirm. :)  Having said that, I have NO idea why you can't go below 100GB.  Not sure if it matters, but for more info's sake, was the original VMDK provisioned as thin or thick? And have all VM snapshots been removed (if there were any)?